# is this necessary to have USB 3.0 port to use USB 3.0 devices?

Tags: windows-8, usb-3

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 1440. And it has only usb 2.0 ports. I want to use USB 3.0 device.  Is it necessary to have USB 3.0 port installed in it.  If possible, then how?

In my laptop there is ExpressCard slot. What is the use of this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need a USB 3 host/port to use USB 3 devices.  However, you will not get USB 3 speeds.  As of right now, all USB devices and controllers are backwards and forwards compatible.  They will operate at the lowest speed though.  Check out Wikipedia's USB [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) for more information.

USB 3.0 was released in November 2008. The standard defines a new SuperSpeed mode with a signalling speed of 5 Gbit/s and a usable data rate of up to 4 Gbit/s.

USB 2.0 was released in April 2000, adding higher maximum signaling rate of 480 Mbit/s (effective throughput up to 35 MB/s or 280 Mbit/s)

As for the [ExpressCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard) slot, it is an interface to allow peripheral devices to be connected to a computer.  So if you really wanted to get USB 3 speeds for your USB 3 devices, you could buy an ExpressCard USB 3 adapter for that slot.  Here is an [example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003HIXOPK).

Comment: Thank you very much.Means I have to buy USB 3 expresse card.